# Placing Zoom Controls in a MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm trying to get the zoom controls to show up in a `mapview`, the following code almost works, but the zoom controls appear in the top left of the `mapview`, not the bottom center like I'm specifying via `setGravity()`.  Can someone enlighten me as to what I'm missing?

```
zoomView = (LinearLayout) mapView.getZoomControls();
zoomView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
zoomView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
mapView.addView(zoomView);
```

These views/layouts are all constructed programmatically, there is no layout file to tweak.

Answer (score 23):

Add the following line to the `OnCreate()` method of your `MapView` Class:

`view.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);`

Answer (score 19):

The trick here is to place another Layout container where you want to put the ZoomControls and then insert the ZoomControls into that.

The real trick is to use the `RelativeLayout` rather than `LinearLayout` to position the elements, as shown in this sample `layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/myMapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="MY_MAP_API_KEY"
  />
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_zoom" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
  /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

The *layout_zoom* LinearLayout element is positioned in the bottom center of the screen, placing it over the middle/bottom of the `MapView`.

Then within your Activity's `onCreate`, get a reference to the *layout_zoom* element and insert the ZoomControl into it, much like you've already done:

```
LinearLayout zoomLayout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_zoom);  
View zoomView = myMapView.getZoomControls(); 
zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
myMapView.displayZoomControls(true);
```

The ZoomControls should now appear on a long click, without stealing the map touch events.

Comment: hello there, can I edit your answer, to add an implementation on WebView? Just a couple 4-5 lines. I use google and found this solution. But, to use it on WebView, I need to modify a bit.

Answer (score 7):

The above didn't work for me, but this does (to place the control on the bottom right):

```
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
ZoomButtonsController zbc = mapView.getZoomButtonsController();
ViewGroup container = zbc.getContainer();
for (int i = 0; i < container.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = container.getChildAt(i);
    if (child instanceof ZoomControls) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM;
        child.requestLayout();
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Finally. An answer that works WITHOUT calling the deprecated getZoomControls() method. Kudos to you. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, a much better solution which allows you to retain the built in zoom controls complete with fade in/out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Reto : thanks for your reply, but the idea was to do it *without* using XML layouts.

I eventually worked out the problem.  Because a MapView is a subclass of ViewGroup, you can easily add child views (like the zoom controls).  All you need is a MapView.LayoutParams instance and you're good to go.  I did something like this (puts zoom controls in the bottom center of the mapview).

```
  // layout to insert zoomcontrols at the bottom center of a mapview
  MapView.LayoutParams params = MapView.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    mapViewWidth / 2, mapViewHeight,
    MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);

  // add zoom controls
  mapView.addView(mapView.getZoomControls(), params);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I cant add a comment to Jason Hudgins approved solution from Nov 28 at 6:32 but I got a tiny error with his code:

In this line:

```
MapView.LayoutParams params = MapView.LayoutParams(
```

The error Eclipse gave me was

> "The method LayoutParams(int, int,
>   int, int, int) is undefined for the
>   type MapView"

instead, creating a new MapView.LayoutParams object fixed it, like this:

```
MapView.LayoutParams params = **new** MapView.LayoutParams(
```

It took me some time to find out, as I am a n00b :D

Answer (score 2):

from the [google groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b4a12843cd33497b) i found this:

ZoomControls without XML:

```
   public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity {  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        setContentView(relativeLayout);

        final MapView mapView = new MapView(this, DEBUG_MAP_API_KEY);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mapViewLayoutParams = new
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT );
        relativeLayout.addView(mapView, mapViewLayoutParams);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zoomControlsLayoutParams = new
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
        zoomControlsLayoutParams.addRule
(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        zoomControlsLayoutParams.addRule
(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        relativeLayout.addView(mapView.getZoomControls(),
zoomControlsLayoutParams);

        mapView.setClickable(true);
        mapView.setEnabled(true);

 }
```

was 100% working for me with SDK1.1

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
MapView map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reto - the problem with using FILL_PARENT is that the zoom control then "steals" all of the touch events; so that you can't pan the map while the zoom controls are visible. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: You're right. Hadn't noticed that. Replaced previous answer with a better solution that avoids this problem.