# How to move Zoom buttons on MapView to different place?

Tags: android, button, reference, position, zooming

I need to move zoom buttons from bottom center to bottom right position on MapView? Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Placing Zoom Controls in a MapView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263507/placing-zoom-controls-in-a-mapview)

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off the built in zoom controls via [setBuiltInZoomControls](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#setBuiltInZoomControls%28boolean%29) and replace them with your own version that develop.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to avoid that. I was looking through available methods and it is possible to reference zoom buttons or container that holds them. What I was not able to do was to move that container. I assume I need to create layout parameters and apply them to the container, but my every attempt was ending with error.