# How to change the position of the Map controller in MapView in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview

How to change the position of the Map controller (zoon in/out) in MapView in android other than the default position in the bottom ?

Comment: I'm going to assume that you're talking about the zoom controls.  If that is the case, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263507/placing-zoom-controls-in-a-mapview/325159#325159).  I understand that getZoomControls is deprecated, but I don't see any other way of getting the view associated with the zoom controls in the MapView API docs.

Comment: I edited my comment with a little bit more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zoomView = (LinearLayout) mapView.getZoomControls();

zoomView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams
  (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

zoomView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
mapView.addView(zoomView);
```