# I couldn't move zoom control button on mapview

Tags: android, zooming, android-mapview

I want to move it on top of mapview. how can i change?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: what you have tried for these?

Comment: Refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263507/placing-zoom-controls-in-a-mapview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
zoomView = (LinearLayout) mapView.getZoomControls();

zoomView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams


(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,


 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

zoomView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
mapView.addView(zoomView);
```

Comment: I'm trying this way Hardik. thx